# Scrapy crawler does not scrape or print results in CSV

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

Seems like this scrapy spider locates the links that it is supposed to go to in order to collect additional information, but it either doesn't go to the next page or it is unable to collect the information on the other page. I checked the xpath links, they all appear to be correct.

Terminal output:

```
2017-01-10 10:31:16 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 213 pages (at 23 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import types
import time
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

import requests
import msgpack

from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector, Selector
from resume_data.items import ResumeDataItem, ResultListItem, WorkItem, SchoolItem, ItemList

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag, NavigableString, Comment
from bs4.element import NavigableString

class ResumeIndeedSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "indeed_resume"
allowed_domains = ["indeed.com"]
start_urls = ['http://www.indeed.com/resumes/mechanical-engineer',
              'http://www.indeed.com/resumes/mechanical-engineering',
              'http://www.indeed.com/resumes/piping-engineer',
              'http://www.indeed.com/resumes/design-engineer',
              'http://www.indeed.com/resumes/project-engineer']

#def __init__(self, filename=None):
        #self.unis    =   list()


rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths = ('//a[contains(@class,"app_link")]')), callback = "parse_item", follow = True),)


def parse_item(self, response):
    hxs     =   Selector(response)
    digest  =   hxs.xpath('//ol[@class="resultsList"]')
    records =   ResumeDataItem()

    url_prefix = 'http://www.indeed.com'

    resume_links   =   digest.xpath('//li[@class="sre"]//div[@class="sre-entry"]')
    names   =   digest.xpath('//a[@target="_blank"]/text()').extract()
    links   =   digest.xpath('//a[@target="_blank"]/@href').extract()

    for name, link in zip(names,links):
        if name not in 'Feedback':
            records['name'] =   name
            records['link'] =   url_prefix+link
            yield Request(records['link'], meta={'item': records}, callback= self.parse_node)


def parse_node(self, response):
    hxs     =   Selector(response)
    records =   ResumeDataItem()

#        name    =   hxs.xpath('/text()').extract()
    name        =   hxs.xpath('//h1[@id="resume-contact"]/text()').extract()
    headline    =   hxs.xpath('//h2[@id="headline"]/text()').extract()
#        locale      =   hxs.xpath('//div[@class="addr" and @itemprop="address"]//p//text()').extract()
    rlocale      =   hxs.xpath('//p[@id="headline_location" and @class="locality"]//text()').extract()
    summary     =   hxs.xpath('//p[@id="res_summary" and @class="summary"]/text()').extract()
    skills      =   list()
    skill       =   hxs.xpath('//div[@id="skills-items" and @class="items-container"]//p//text()').extract()
    if len(skill) != 0:
        skills.append(''.join(skill).encode('utf-8'))        
    skill       =   hxs.xpath('//div[@id="additionalinfo-section" and @class="last"]//div[@class="data_display"]//p//text()').extract()
    if len(skill) != 0:
        skills.append(''.join(skill).encode('utf-8'))        

    resume_links    =   list()
    links       =   hxs.xpath('//div[@id="link-items" and @class="items-container"]//p//text()').extract()
    for link in links:
        resume_links.append(''.join(link).encode('utf-8'))

    workHistory =   ItemList()
    experience  =   hxs.xpath('//div[@id="work-experience-items"]/div')
    for elem in experience:
        item = elem.xpath('div')
        for entry in item:
            workEntry   =   WorkItem()

            title       =   entry.xpath('p[@class="work_title title"]//text()').extract()
            workEntry['title']  =   ''.join(title).encode('utf-8')

            company     =   entry.xpath('div[@class="work_company"]/span/text()').extract()
            workEntry['company']=   ''.join(company).encode('utf-8')

            location    =   entry.xpath('div[@class="work_company"]/div[@class="inline-block"]/span/text()').extract()
            workEntry['work_location']  =   ''.join(company).encode('utf-8')

            dates       =   entry.xpath('p[@class="work_dates"]//text()').extract()
            dates_str   =   ''.join(dates).encode('utf-8').split(' to ')
            if len(dates) > 0:
                if dates_str[0]:
                    workEntry['start_date'] =   dates_str[0]
                if dates_str[1]:
                    workEntry['end_date']   =   dates_str[1]
            else:
                workEntry['start_date'] =   'NULL'
                workEntry['end_date']   =   'NULL'


            description =   entry.xpath('p[@class="work_description"]//text()').extract()
            workEntry['description']    =   ''.join(description).encode('utf-8')

            workHistory.container.append(workEntry)

    eduHistory =   ItemList()
    education  =   hxs.xpath('//div[@id="education-items" and @class="items-container"]/div')
    for elem in education:
        item = elem.xpath('div')
        for entry in item:
            eduEntry    =   SchoolItem()

            degree      =   entry.xpath('p[@class="edu_title"]/text()').extract()
            degree      =   ''.join(degree).encode('utf-8')
            eduEntry['degree']  =   degree

            school      =   entry.xpath('div[@class="edu_school"]/span//text()').extract()
            school      =   ''.join(school).encode('utf-8')
            eduEntry['school']  =   school

            locale      =   entry.xpath('span[@itemprop="addressLocality"]/text()').extract()
            locale      =   ''.join(locale).encode('utf-8')
            eduEntry['locale']  =   locale

            grad_date   =   entry.xpath('p[@class="edu_dates"]/text()').extract()
            dates_str   =   ''.join(grad_date).encode('utf-8').split(' to ')
            if len(grad_date) > 0:
                if len(dates_str) == 2:
                    if dates_str[0]:
                        eduEntry['admit_date']  =   dates_str[0]
                    try:
                        if dates_str[1]:
                            eduEntry['grad_date']   =   dates_str[1]
                    except:
                        pass
                elif len(dates_str) == 1:
                    if dates_str[0]:
                        eduEntry['grad_date']  =   dates_str[0]
                        eduEntry['admit_date'] =   'NULL'
            else:
                eduEntry['admit_date']  =   'NULL'
                eduEntry['grad_date']   =   'NULL'

            eduHistory.container.append(eduEntry)

    records['url']      =   response.url
    records['name']     =   ''.join(name).encode('utf-8')
    records['headline'] =   msgpack.packb(''.join(headline).encode('utf-8'))
    records['locale']   =   ''.join(rlocale).encode('utf-8')
    records['summary']  =   msgpack.packb(''.join(summary).encode('utf-8'))
    records['skills']   =   msgpack.packb(skills)
    records['links']    =   resume_links
    #records['experience']   =   msgpack.packb(workHistory, default=workHistory.encode)
    records['experience'] = workHistory
    records['education']    =   msgpack.packb(eduHistory, default=eduHistory.encode)
    #records['experience']   =   workHistory
    #records['education']    =   eduHistory

    return records`
```

Comment: Try to run the spider with loglevel DEBUG. It will probably show you what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this part of code

```
for name, link in zip(names,links):
    if name not in 'Feedback':
        records['name'] =   name
        records['link'] =   url_prefix+link
        yield Request(records['link'], meta={'item': records}, callback= self.parse_node)
```

doesn't emit any link. Perhaps you meant `if 'Feedback' not in name`

Also note that XPath here `digest.xpath('//a[@target="_blank"]/text()')` applied to DOM overall, not only part previously extracted for `digest`. If you'd like to apply XPath to `digest` selector you should rather use leading dot in xpath like this `digest.xpath('.//a[@target="_blank"]/text()')`